# Soft keyboard issure

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, window-resize

I am trying to adjust my screen when the soft keyboard loads. The normal screen looks like this.
[image]

However when the user clicks the EditText, the view gets disrupted and appears like this. In my manifest for the activity I have added the following **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**
[image]

What I would like to happen is that both the buttons at the bottom appear and the entire Edittext is visible without being cut when the user clicks on the EditText.

Edit: Adding the following line to my activity **getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);** made my view look like this. But I still want my two buttons to appear at the bottom of the EditText
[image]

**XML for the bottom EditText and Buttons**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.6  "
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText

                android:hint="Enter your Message"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/messageET"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/lightrectangle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/addimgbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="#f6f6f6"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/blueadd" />

                    <TextView
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Add an image"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addimgbtn"
                       />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/lightrectangle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                        android:background="#f6f6f6"
                        android:src="@mipmap/bluesend" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Send Message"
                        android:id="@+id/sendmsgTV"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sendbtn"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're going to have to post at least a simplified version of your layout.  Resize is what you want, but there needs to be a view it actually can resize.

Comment: @GabeSechan what would I have to resize?

Comment: That central list would need to be shrinkable.

Comment: A simple example would be if it all was I a relative, with the buttons aligned to patent bottom and the list above the text view and set to fill patent. That would work (the list would take all available room

Comment: @GabeSechan check the edited response

Answer (score 1):

Add a the fields or layout inside a scroll view this will auto adjust your layout. You can scroll your layout and it is auto adjustable in all screens.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1.6  "
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageET"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your Message" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/lightrectangle" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addimgbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#f6f6f6"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/blueadd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addimgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Add an image"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/lightrectangle" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:background="#f6f6f6"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/bluesend" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sendmsgTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sendbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Send Message"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```